# How do I write hbase data to HDFS as text

Tags: hdfs, hbase

There are already 300,000 pieces of data of that day in HBASE, how to write the data into HBASE in TXT format, and each TXT file corresponds to the data of a day, such as:
2020.03.25/high.TXT（High is the name of the table）

Answer (score 0):

You can export HBase to HDFS by using a utility that comes with HBase (using the hbase command):

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export high /path/in/hdfs
```

This will export **all** the data table to a csv file in HDFS. So, if you define your hbase data to contain data for 1 day (by employing the ttl property), you will get the desired results.

If your hbase table contains previous data, then you could use the following command exprt data by timestamp range:

```
echo "scan 'high',{ TIMERANGE => [start_timestamp, end_timestamp] }" | hbase shell | grep "^ " > high.txt
hdfs dfs -put high.txt /path/in/hdfs
```

`start_timestamp` and `end_timestamp` should be defined as you wish (for the last 1 day just set them as the beginning and the end of the day).
Pay attention that it first generates high.txt in your local file system, so use it when you have sufficient storage (or high doesn't contain too much data for a single day).

Comment: What I need is to write a program that imports the hbase data into HDFS by itself rather than by command. The data in HBASE is the data of a day, and the data in HBASE has been timestamped. (we jar the program, upload it to the server, and then run it on the server. We can't execute it all the way through the command.)

Comment: All the data is in a table

Comment: ok. It was not clear from your question. Look at phoenix (https://phoenix.apache.org/). You can use it to make time-based queries on hbase. It has sdk to several programming languages.